# HP ALM API query to form endpoint

Tags: rest, api, alm

I am trying to hit the ALM API call to get the response.

```
URL: http://myalm.com:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/project/projects/produc/tests?fields=id,name,status&query={owner["myname"]}
```

Here am trying to extract the **ID, name and status** and passing the query as **owner=myname**.

After hitting in API call i am getting below mentioned error -

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0. Undefined path parameters are:
>   owner["myname"]**

I posted the same url in browser and there its fetching me the correct response.
Not sure how to pass query in API call, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode special characters (commas) in your URL (browser does it automatically for you).
See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for details.

Comment: Even i tried the encoding, but no use. Seems for the API we need to build the Endpoint in different way.

Comment: Maybe you can post your code, so it will be easier to check if there is an issue with it

Comment: Response response = APIUtil.getCallWithHeaderParamCookies(headersGET,cookies, "http://SERVER:8080/qcbin/PATH**/PROD/tests?fields=id,name,status&query={owner[rajan]}");

Method:

public static Response getCallWithHeaderParamCookies(Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> cookies, String URL) {

  LoggerUtil.log("GET call on endpoint " + URL + " with headers " + headers.entrySet());
return given().headers(headers).cookies(cookies).request().when().get(URL);
 }

Comment: Error Message i got " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0. Undefined path parameters are: owner[rajan]".

Comment: Use java.net.URLEncoder.encode() to encode your values, e.g.: `"SERVER:8080/qcbin/PATH**/PROD/tests?fields="+encode("id,name,status")+"&query="+encode("{owner[rajan]}")`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of ALM you are using, it's always better to check this in help section when you open ALM. There you will see option to see all exampled of rest APIs that ALM offers.

Generally its like below:-

```
your_query = "defect_id=2330"
your_fields = "id,name,status"

Endpoint_url?query=your_query&fields=your_fields
```